# Google Mini Crawling a SharePoint UNC Path

Tags: search, sharepoint, unc, google-search-appliance

I inherited a Google Mini and am trying to work around the limitation of not being able to index SharePoint (2003) natively. I can map a UNC path to a site's Shared Documents folder in Windows or Mac OS X, but I am stuck somewhere with the Mini. Or am I crazy? Is this not a valid workaround?

For "Start Crawling from the Following URLs:" and "sharepoint.mysite.com\DavWWWRoot\sites\siteName\LibraryName\" I have the following:

```
\\sharepoint.mysite.com\DavWWWRoot\sites\siteName\LibraryName\
```

Since this needs authentication I have the same URL in Crawler Access with a tested username/pwd combo.

The Crawl Diagnostics gives me a `Error: Document not found (404).` for the same URL. (The Mini displays it in the diagnostics as `unc://sharepoint.mysite.com/DavWWWRoot/sites/siteName/LibraryName/`)

Under Network Settings I ran the Network Diagnostics for the aforementioned URL and received the following:

> Test URL  unc://sharepoint.mysite.com/DavWWWRoot/sites/siteName/LibraryName/  returncode 404, should be 200
>   Test URL  unc://sharepoint.mysite.com/DavWWWRoot/sites/siteName/LibraryName/  OK - pingable

Is what I'm trying possible via the Google Mini?

Comment: ckoerner, this should be possible based upon the documentation provided at http://goo.gl/LjKo7 and http://goo.gl/0RqyV. What protocol are you using to map these drives on Mac OS X / Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had posted a link to a product that I wrote which got deleted (You can google to find it).  Mounting via UNC is not the best approach.  However, try using smb:// instead of unc for your pathes.

Comment: I had tried SMB but with the same problems. I'm thinking it has something to do with the server configuration and SharePoint conflicting.